# Is this substring-after and concat breaking my encoding?

Tags: xslt-2.0, google-search-appliance

Our GSA uses a FileConnector to index different shares which are targets of DFS Links. I am trying to rewrite `file://filesrv01.example.com/share$/dir/file.ext` to `file://R:/hare/dir/file.ext` in the frontend XSL.

There is a `xsl:choose` element wich tests for different protocols but not `file://`, so I assume the default handling for my source links would be this node:

```
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="U"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

We created a new `xsl:when` node like this:

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(U, 'file://server.example.com/share$>
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes'
    select="concat('file://R:/share/',
      substring-after(U,'file://server.example.com/share$/') )"/>
</xsl:when>
```

This works for almost all entries in our index, but it fails when the path contains a german umlaut. Following input, actual and expected Output:

```
file://server/share$/dir/FileWithUmläut.txt
file://R:/share/dir/FileWithUmläut.txt
file://R:/share/dir/FileWithUmlÃ¤ut.txt
```

Why is the default `xsl:otherwise` working without changing umlauts but our concat+substring is not? Anything I could check or change?

Edit #1
There is only one output element in the XSL file: `<xsl:output method="html"/>`. The XSL itself is recognised as ANSI in Notepad++ with some Umlauts in UI texts. Output to the browser is utf-8 xhtml.

Edit #2
When I replace the `xsl:when` with the following block, the encoding is not broken and the link can be opened (not using the DFS root but directly using unc). Because of this I believe it is not the encoding of XML or XSL, thanks for your input nevertheless, @MathiasMüller.

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(U, 'file://server.example.com/share$/')">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="U"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: I guess the third line should be the actual output and the second the expected one? In my opinion this has nothing to do with `concat` or `xsl:otherwise`. How are the XML files encoded? What's the encoding of the stylesheet and the encoding attribute of `xsl:output` if this element exists?

Comment: @MathiasMüller the second and third line is the acutal link when copied from internet explorer. The third (non-working) link in the output source is `file://R:/share/dir/FileWithUml%C3%A4.txt`

Comment: This does not answer all of my questions. The input to the transformation is XML - what is its encoding? Can you change the encoding of the stylesheet to UTF-8 and also specify `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>` explicitly?

Comment: When not using XSL, the output is marked as utf8, I must assume this is the underlying encoding for XSL. I try to change the XSL to utf but I don't think this will help, without my xsl:when node the output of the very same file does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specific problem vanished as soon as I used `file:///R:/` instead of `file://R:/` (additional forward slash) but I still try to figure out why that helped. In the GSA XSL there is a JavaScript snippet to "fix" encoding issues in IE but that does not care if the protocol has 2 or 3 slashes.

Although Firefox does not allow the file protocol out of the box, neither syntax works when copied from there. This leads me to believe that my currently installed IE 9 fixes some encoding issues on its own when using the correct `file:///` prefix and Firefox does not.

As we would like the links to work in Firefox too, I will continue my quest for glory in the land of unicode, plagued by the ancient dragon of `file:///` and home to the houses of IE and FF.

Comment: Also, note that changing the url patterns does affect document preview.  Document preview matches the exact U tag.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I soon would have wondered why we have previews for our websites but not for files... It looks like I need to write some javascript to fix PreviewData.